# NamedQueries JPA jax-rs REST WHERE Equals

Tags: rest, jsp, jpa, jax-rs

I'm creating a REST service following [this guide](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html), now I want to get table rows with a specific value in two different columns.

And then be able to present it in JSP.

Is this possible? if so how do I manage to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of how your `yourNameFacadeREST` should look like:

```
@GET
@Override
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<ExampleTable> testFindByName() {
    List<ExampleTable> results = em.createNamedQuery("ExampleTable.findByName", ExampleTable.class)
            .setParameter("firstname", 1)
            .setParameter("lastname", 1)
            .getResultList();
    return results;
}

@GET
@Path("test")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public void findName(
        @Context final HttpServletRequest request,
        @Context final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/foundbyname.jsp");
    request.setAttribute("items", testFindByName());
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

Don't forget to change the @NamedQuery to (as the example follows):

```
@NamedQuery(name = "ExampleTable.findByName", query = "SELECT e FROM ExampleTable e WHERE e.firstname = :firstname AND e.lastname = :lastname")
```

This will find the rows with firstname "1" and lastname "1".

To present it in JSP, you may now use for example:

`<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">`

And then:

```
<p>firstname: ${item.firstname}</p>
```

According to your needs of course.

Comment: OMG Thank you! Finaly!

Comment: @TheIntern No problem, glad I could help :)